# How to count string num with limit memory?

Tags: java, algorithm

The task is to count the num of words from a input file.

the input file is 8 chars per line, and there are 10M lines, for example:

```
aaaaaaaa  
bbbbbbbb  
aaaaaaaa  
abcabcab  
bbbbbbbb  
...
```

the output is:

```
aaaaaaaa 2  
abcabcab 1  
bbbbbbbb 2  
...
```

It'll takes 80MB memory if I load all of words into memory, but there are only 60MB in os system, which I can use for this task. So how can I solve this problem?

My algorithm is to use `map<String,Integer>`, but jvm throw Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space. I know I can solve this by setting -Xmx1024m, for example, but I want to use less memory to solve it.

Comment: Can you please explain your algorithm?

Comment: How do you read the file ? Example of relevant part of your code would help.

Comment: Is swapping an option to you? In most systems, there is enough disk storage, but it would slow down the process significantly of course.

Comment: Can you use disk space? If so how many space can you use?

Comment: I assume this is `[homework]`?

Comment: You can solve this with constant memory and no additional disk space by reading the file multiple times.

Comment: Do you have to do it in Java? Otherwise you can just use the standard Unix tools `sort` and `uniq`: At its simplest it's just `sort $FILE | uniq -c`, but you might have to sort temporarily into another file if the input is too big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suck at explaining theoretical answers but here we go....

I have made an assumption about your question as it is not entirely clear.

- The memory used to store all the distinct words is 80MB (the entire file is bigger).
- The words could contain non-ascii characters (so we just treat the data as raw bytes).

It is sufficient to read over the file twice storing ~ 40MB of distinct words each time.

```
//  Loop over the file and for each word:
//
//      Compute a hash of the word. 
//      Convert the hash to a number by some means (skip if possible).
//      If the number is odd then skip to the next word. 
//      Use conventional means to store the distinct word. 
//
//  Do something with all the distinct words.
```

Then repeat the above a second time using `even` instead of `odd`.

Then you have divided the task into 2 and can do each separately. 
No words from the first set will appear in the second set.

The hash is necessary because the words could (in theory) all end with the same letter.

The solution can be extended to work with different memory constraints. Rather than saying just odd/even we can divide the words into X groups by using `number MOD X`.

Comment: You've traded a problem for another. Your hash algorithm may well return an odd number for every word, or the same value `mod x` for every word.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström The data would have to be specifically crafted for such an event to occur. Random and/or real world data would not that have that effect with a decent hash algorithm. Simple patterns in the data won't favour even/odd in the hash.

Comment: Well, it's the same caveat as yours, that the data may have been specifically crafted to have each word end with the same letter.

Comment: There are real use cases for words ending in the same letter (consider a list of actions: dancing, running, drawing). The list of words that would result in bad hashes has no real use case. This is the difference.

Comment: If the data has been crafted to break the implementation then the data isn't very useful anyway so there would be no motivation to check it.

Answer (score 7):

I believe that the most robust solution is to use the disk space.

For example you can sort your file in another file, using an algorithm for sorting large files (that use disk space), and then count the consecutive occurrences of the same word.

I believe that this [post](http://www.codeodor.com/index.cfm/2007/5/14/Re-Sorting-really-BIG-files---the-Java-source-code/1208) can help you. Or search by yourself something about [external sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting).

**Update 1**

Or as *@jordeu* suggest you can use a Java embedded database library: like H2, JavaDB, or similars.

**Update 2**

I thought about another possible solution, using [Prefix Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_tree). However I still prefer the first one, because I'm not an expert on them.

Comment: This indeed is the right solution for a file of any size. It's more work, but uses constant amount of memory that is not dependant on the data.

Comment: @Slanec, wrong. **If** the input file is too big to fit into memory at once, **and** speed is not of the essence, **and** there is enough free disk space available, then yes.

Comment: @PéterTörök the question ask to not use more then 60MB, so there are the limits of the problem.

Comment: Indeed, in this case. @Slanec, however, seems to claim this is the best general solution, with which I disagree.

Comment: LOL, I came to the same idea without reading you answer first. +1.

Comment: @MisterSmith maybe you do many time the same procedure with `sort` and `uniq` :D

Comment: But I don't see the need to sort. This could take considerable time, and swapping lines in a file is expensive. I'd just iterate over the input file and keep a record of the counts in a file. The format of the output file can be designed so that finding a word is fast, without reading the entire line and comparing char by char the strings. In this sense he can keep advantage of the fixed length of each line, and come up with a random access file (records) of some kind.

Answer (score 5):

Read one line at a time
and then have e.g. a `HashMap<String,Integer>`
where you put your words as key and the count as integer.

If a key exists, increase the count. Otherwise add the key to the map with a count of 1.

There is no need to keep the whole file in memory.

Comment: But if all the words are different?

Comment: That is the corner case - but if you know that in advance, you could just count the lines ;-)

Comment: This, I'd just make it `HashMap<Integer,Integer>`, for the key would be hashcode of the String. Also, a MUCH more memory-wise HashMap implementation for this would be [Trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/)'s [`TIntIntHashMap`](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/map/hash/TIntIntHashMap.html), because it doesn't store a big autoboxed `Integer`, but a pure `int`.

Comment: Heiko's solution is the best and easiest.

Comment: His words is 8 chars. In ASCII they are 8 bytes if he is sure about that, or 16 bytes if he cannot use only ASCII chars. However with a HashMap entry you don't saving too many bytes: int + int = 8 + the space of the entry object.

Comment: I just use this algorithm with java, but jvm throws Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: @vienna use the readLine() method. You don't have to keep the file in memory. Like this  `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ras));
        String s;
       while((s=fileReader.readLine())!=null)
{ //add to map} `

Comment: @Tito you know how much size an HashMap.Entry<String,Integer> consumes?

Comment: @dash1e As Slanec said above TIntIntHashMap would be a good option in that case. Can reduce the memory consumption by a good amount.

Comment: keys are references and also consume memory. This is no solution.

Comment: And finally how can you output the results? You will have an int an then? What's the word about it?

Comment: @TitoGeorge I also use readLine method to save line into map.but jvm throw outofmemory exception

Comment: @vienna Can you also try TIntIntHashMap or TObjectIntMap as Slance Said? It is like normal map, but allows primitives as key values. Helps to reduce memory utilization significantly.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you mean the number of *distinct* words do you?

So the obvious approach is to store (distinctive information about) each different word as a key in a map, where the value is the associated counter. Depending on how many distinct words are expected, storing all of them may even fit into your memory, however not in the worst case scenario when all words are different.

To lessen memory needs, you could calculate a checksum for the words and store that, instead of the words themselves. Storing e.g. a 4-byte checksum instead of an 8-character word (requiring at least 9 bytes to store) requires 40M instead of 90M. Plus you need a counter for each word too. Depending on the expected number of occurrences for a specific word, you may be able to get by with 2 bytes (for max 65535 occurrences), which requires max 60M of memory for 10M distinct words.

#### Update

Of course, the checksum can be calculated in many different ways, and it can be lossless or not. This also depends a lot on the character set used in the words. E.g. if only lowercase standard ASCII characters are used (as shown in the examples above), we have 26 different characters at each position. Consequently, each character can be losslessly encoded in 5 bits. Thus 8 characters fit into 5 bytes, which is a bit more than the limit, but *may* be dense enough, depending on the circumstances.

Comment: Wouldn't calculating checksum for each unique word be time consuming?

Comment: Different words can have same checksum.

Comment: If they have the same checksum, you were using the wrong algorithm to compute it :->

Comment: I agree with @dash1e, and even if they don't, then you're not adding value compared to storing words. Also, to answer adarshr, pure hash functions (e.g. MD5) are designed for speed.

Comment: Heiko, how should you know that in advance?

Comment: @adarshr, sometimes you have to decide whether you optimize for speed or memory efficiency. You can't always have both.

Comment: I am convinced that the use of external sorting or other algorithm that work with disk, as I explain in my answer, would be the best solution.

Comment: @Romain, do you mean that completing successfully instead of terminating with out of memory error is no added value?

Comment: @dash1e, could be, depending on the circumstances. E.g. speed requirements - sorting using external files is a lot slower than just reading through the input file once. Since the problem is ill defined, we can't reliably decide about the best solution - but my vote would go for the simplest one which works.

Comment: This approach has a drawback: if the input problem grows in size (number of lines), or if the hash function output value is bigger as the word length grows, then you run into the same problem. My proposal is in my answer.

Comment: @MisterSmith, indeed, as all approaches, this one has its drawbacks too. Since the problem is badly defined, we can make a host of generalizing or specializing assumptions and tailor our solutions according to these. But I personally don't like speculative generality :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use [H2 Database Engine](http://www.h2database.com/), it can work on disc or on memory if it's necessary. And it have a really good performance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a SHA-1 of each word, then store these numbers in a Set.  Then, of course, when reading a number, check the Set if it's there [(not totally necessary since Set by definition is unique, so you can just "add" its SHA-1 number also)]

Comment: What is the SHA-1 result size?

Comment: I do believe you are correct :), bah, throw all the words into a Set of Strings, and let Java deal with it.  It must be optimized by now!  lol.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what kind of character the words are build of you can chose for this system:

If it might contain any character of the alphabet in upper and lower case, you will have (26*2)^8 combinations, which is 281474976710656. This number can fit in a long datatype.

So compute the checksum for the strings like this:

```
public static long checksum(String str)
{
    String tokes = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    long checksum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i)
    {
        int c = tokens.indexOf(str.charAt(i));

        checksum *= tokens.length();
        checksum += c;
    }

    return checksum;
}
```

This will reduce the taken memory per word by more than 8 bytes. A string is an array of `char`, each char is in Java 2 bytes. So, 8 chars = 16 bytes. But the string class contains more data than only the char array, it contains some integers for size and offset as well, which is 4 bytes per int. Don't forget the memory pointer to the Strings and char arrays as well. So, a raw estimation makes me think that this will reduce 28 bytes per word.

So, 8 bytes per word and you have 10 000 000 words, gives 76 MB. Which is your first wrong estimation, because you forgot all the things I noticed. So this means that even this method won't work.

Comment: 8 chars, and you are using only ASCII chars are 8 bytes. One long is 8 bytes, so what are you saving?

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux thank you, I just wonder why a string will cost more memory than I estimate. so I need some other algorithm to solve it.

Comment: Because an "empty" (= no characters) takes also a lot of bytes (I estimated it at 28 bytes per String object.

Answer (score 0):

If you can sort your file first (e.g. using the memory-efficient "sort" utility on Unix), then it's easy.  You simply read the the sorted items, counting the neighboring duplicates as you go, and write the totals to a new file immediately.

If you need to sort using Java, this post might help:

http://www.codeodor.com/index.cfm/2007/5/10/Sorting-really-BIG-files/1194

Answer (score 0):

You can convert each 8 byte word into a `long` and use `TLongIntHashMap` which is quite a bit more efficient than `Map<String, Integer>` or `Map<Long, Integer>`

If you just need the distinct words you can use `TLongHashSet`

Answer (score 0):

You can use constant memory by reading your file multiple times.

Basic idea:

Treat the file as n partitions p_1...p_n, sized so that you can load each of them into ram.

1. Load p_i into a Map structure, scan through the whole file and keep track of counts of the p_i elements only (see answer of Heiko Rupp)
2. Remove element if we encounter the same value in a partition p_j with j smaller i
3. Output result counts for elements in the Map
4. Clear Map, repeat for all p_1...p_n

Answer (score 0):

As in any optimization, there are tradeoffs. In your case, you can do the same task with less memory but it comes at the cost of increasing runtime.

Your scarce resource is memory, so you can't store the words in RAM.

You could use a hash instead of the word as other posts mention, but if your file grows in size this is no solution, since at some point you'll run into the same problem again.

Yes, you could use an external web server to crunch the file and do the job for your client app, but reading your question it seems that you want to do all the thing in one (your app).

So my proposal is to iterate over the file, and for each word:

- If the word was found for first time, write the string to a result file together with the integer value 1.
- If the word was processed before (it will appear in the result file), increment the record value.

This solution scales well no matter the number of lines of your input file nor the length of the words*.

You can optimize the way you do the writes in the output file, so that the search is made faster, but the basic version described above is enough to work.

EDIT:
*It scales well until you run out of disk space XD. So the precondition would be to have a disk with at least 2N bytes of free usable space, where N is the input file size in bytes.

Comment: The hash table doesn't need to include the full text data, it could simply include the offset of a place the line appears in the original file.

Comment: @Random832 Even in that case, if the number of strings in the input file is large enough, the hashtable won't fit in memory. (I know he said only 10M strings, but I was trying to describe a more general solution)

Answer (score 0):

possible solutions:

1. Use file sorting and then just count the consequent occurences of each value.
2. Load the file in a database and use a count statement like this: `select value, count(*) from table group by value`